# Why can I not click a small CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, multiline, checkedlistbox

I have created a CheckedListBox control with 4 elements in C#.  Multicolumn is set to true.  As soon as I make the height of the control small enough to contain only a single row, I can no longer interact with the control with the cursor when I execute the program.  If I make the height one unit (pixel?) larger, so that there are 2 columns of 2 rows, behavior returns to normal.

When the cursor cannot interact with the CheckedListBox, I can still tab to it, toggle between its elements with the arrow keys, and check/uncheck elements with the space bar.  I just cannot use the cursor.

Comment: Works on my machine.  This doesn't make for great UI.  Google "winforms checked combobox".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me... I'm experiencing the same thing occasionally.  It happens when (1) the CheckedListBox is 1 row high, and (2) the items in it extend ANY past the right edge of the control.  If the control is made a little wider, the mouse clicking works again. (You can test that theory by anchoring the CheckedListBox Left/Right and resizing the form.  Now it works, now it don't.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like setting the width to be total column width + 4 also works.

There is a minimum width such that all columns are fully displayed that must be met before you can interact with it via mouse cursor.